# Domain glassfish requires authentication with the realm 'dolmen'

Tags: glassfish

In my work I give support to users, and the following problem has been sent to me.

Logs Jenkins: (Automated tests that run in the night)

> [HttpAuthenticationRequestFilter$UPDCredentialsProvider] Domain
>   request authentication with the realm 'dolmen'

Logs Server:

> 23/01/2018 01:28:25.637 [http-thread-pool-8080(15)] WARN java.util.logging.Logger.doLog WEB9102: Web Login Failed:
>   com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
>   23/01/2018 01:28:25.646 [http-thread-pool-8080(29)] ERROR java.util.logging.Logger.doLog jdbcrealm.invaliduserreason

Via asadmin I've checked that the realm dolmen exists

```
asadmin> list-auth-realms
Authentication failed with password from login store: /root/.asadminpass
Enter admin password for user "admin">
admin-realm
file
certificate
dolmen
pnf-realm
Command list-auth-realms executed successfully.
asadmin>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 1)

I was able to reproduce the error in SOAPUI. During the call to the web service, I noticed that if I change a letter in the login user or password, I can see the error message : " request authentication with the realm 'dolmen'"

[Log SOAPUI:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ivzl.jpg)

But as you can see, in the image "Log SOAPUI:" I also have a HTTP 401.

In SoapUI Preferences, I notice that the option "Authenticate Preemptively" was disable. After enable the option "Authenticate Preemptively" I was able to finish a test in my local machine without error.

In the machine where Jenkins is installed (Where the Automated tests run in the night), I notice that the file soapui-preferences.xml does not exist. So maybe the solution for the problem is here.

I'm waiting for a time frame to be able to test without impacting testers.

I will keep you posted.

UPDATE 2)

To get rid of this problem I've rebuild my glassfish domain.